# Gnome Builder set source directory for CMake projects

Tags: cmake, builder, gnome-builder

I have a project whose directory structure is:

```
Application
 |_Project
 | |_CMakeLists.txt
 | |_source.cpp
 | |_...
 |_other stuff
 |_...
```

Now, I have opened the "Project" folder in Builder, which contains CMakeLists.txt and the sources for the app, but Builder instead opened the parent directory ("Application"), and set the build configuration to build sources from there. Naturally, the build failed because the folder "Application" indeed does not contain any sources or CMakeLists.txt. I have entered the Build configurations screen in Builder, but the text box which shows the source directory is read-only, and set to the "Application" folder. I could not do anything to get Builder to open the "Project" subfolder as the project directory, even if I select one of its subfolders, it still opens the "Application" parent directory. What can I do to open only and ONLY the inner "Source" folder? Moving the sources to the "Application" folder is not an option, since there are other folders containing other stuff there, and it is a fairly large project whose directory tree shall remain unchanged, in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you open instead of the 'directory' the CMakeLists.txt it should work. The directory always looks for the .git parent and setups the directory there. You can choose which file should be used in the open project dialog on the right bottom.